# is this expression "what does a panda look like" too childish?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

Assume I've never seen a panda before. When people mention this animal, I ask

> What does a panda look like?

I googled this sentence, there are only "1,020 results".

Is this expression too childish?

Comment: No, it's a perfectly natural way to ask. It's just that there aren't too many people out there wondering what a panda looks like.

Comment: Google isn't a curated English corpus. It's not instructive to use it in order to derive conclusions about the English language. Moreover, the number of results it reports is a mere approximation, and often a very inaccurate one.

Comment: @Minty this would make a good answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does a panda look like?

is a perfectly grammatical and natural way to ask this ques5tion -- in fact I can't think of a better or more natural way off-hand. Nor do i see anything childish about this, except perhaps that a child is more likely not to already know what a panda looks like.

As the comments suggest, the number of google results for a phrase is not a good measure of how grammatical or idiomatic that phrase is. The google ngram viewer is somewhat better, but will not handle phrases more than a few words long (I think the limit is 5 words), and there are sources of systematic bias in the tests that make up the underlying corpus.